# React Hooks Getting data from inside an object state

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, state

I'm using react hooks to access a state information. In my code, I pass state from one page to another and is successfully able to access it. This is my working code, so far:

```
    import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

    import { showById, changeStatus } from '../../services/teachers';

    import './styles.css';

    function TeacherPage(props) {
        const [data, setData] = useState(props.location.state);
        const [teacherInfo, setTeacherInfo] = useState(data);
        const [nameInfo, setNameInfo] = useState();

        function handleTeacherInfo(id){
            id = data.teacher._id;
            const response = api.get(`/teacher/${id}`);
            setTeacherInfo(response);
            console.log(teacherInfo);
            setNameInfo(teacherInfo.name)
            console.log(nameInfo);
        }

        useEffect(() =>{
            handleTeacherInfo();
        }, [data])

        return (
        <div className="teacherPage">
            <div className="contentTeacherPage">
                <h1>Professor(a) {data.teacher.name}</h1>
                <div clasname="teacherInfoCard" key={data.teacher._id}>
                    <span>{data.teacher.name}</span>
                    <br></br>
                    <span>{data.teacher._id}</span>
                    <br></br>
                    <span>{data.teacher.email}</span>
                    <br></br>
                    <span>{data.teacher.education}</span>
                    <br></br>
                    <span>Status: {data.teacher.approved}</span>
                    <br></br>
                    <span>{data.teacher.cpf}</span>
                    <br></br>
                    <span>{data.teacher.info}</span>
                    <br></br>
                    <span>{data.teacher.rating}</span>
                    <br></br>
                    <span>{data.teacher.subjects[0]} e {data.teacher.subjects[1]}</span>
                    <br></br>
                    <span>{data.teacher.education[0]}</span>
                    <br></br>
                    {/* {data.teacher && data.teacher.teacher.map((teacher) => {
                        return (
                            <span>alalal</span>
                        )
                    })} */}
                    <button onClick={approveTeacher}>Aprovar</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default TeacherPage;
```

I am able to access data with this lengthy-expression, `{data.teacher.<field>}`, but I was looking to pass them all to a state so I would be able to map it, because some of these fields are arrays.

In the function below, I am setting the teacherInfo state as the response from the api.get and able to see all of its data, but am unable to see specific data from the state.

`console.log(teacherInfo)` returns the data, but `console.log(teacherInfo.name)` returns `undefined (name is an existing field)`.

```
       function handleTeacherInfo(id){
            id = data.teacher._id;
            const response = showById(id);
            setTeacherInfo(response);
            console.log(teacherInfo);
            setNameInfo(teacherInfo.name)
            console.log(nameInfo);
        }
```

How can I get specific data from the state? I believe either I'm missing something or I'm declaring something wrong, but I don't know what.

For better visualization, console.log(teacherInfo) return is this:

```
teacher:
    approved: false
    availableDays: "asasas"
    classPrice: "R$ 500,00"
    degree: "ddsdsds"
    email: "pedro@gmail.com"
    info: "asasas"
    name: "Pedro"
    rating: 10
    registerDate: "2021-01-21T17:19:07.565Z"
    subjects: ["6001e73106a211004877f6e2"]
    __t: "Teacher"
    __v: 0
    _id: "6009b78b3c4c35001d19a346"
```

Console.log(teacherInfo.name) returns `undefined`, but should return `Pedro`

Comment: *How can I get specific data from the state?* In the same way that you access objects in JS, using dot notation.

Comment: ok, but for example. Being able to return ```teacherInfo``` as an object, I understand that returning ```teacherInfo.name``` would return it's name. But this is returning undefined, so I believe either I'm missing something or I'm declaring something wrong, but don't know what. I've edited the question to be more specific.

Comment: Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

`setState` is asynchronous, so you cannot guarantee that `teacherInfo` will have been updated when you attempt to call `setNameInfo()`.

You should use the [`useEffect()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) hook for that, and pass in `teacherInfo` as a dependancy using the [second parameter](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects):

```js
useEffect(() => { 
    setNameInfo(teacherInfo?.name);
}, [ teacherInfo ]);
```